# How to correctly get layer weights from Conv2D in keras?

Tags: keras, convolution, keras-layer

I have Conv2D layer defines as:

```
Conv2D(96, kernel_size=(5, 5),
             activation='relu',
             input_shape=(image_rows, image_cols, 1),
             kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_normal(seed),
             bias_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed),
             padding='same',
             name='conv_1')
```

This is the first layer in my network. 
Input dimensions are 64 by 160, image is 1 channel. 
I am trying to visualize weights from this convolutional layer but not sure how to get them. 
Here is how I am doing this now:

1.Call

```
layer.get_weights()[0]
```

This returs an array of shape (5, 5, 1, 96). 1 is because images are 1-channel.

2.Take 5 by 5 filters by

```
layer.get_weights()[0][:,:,:,j][:,:,0]
```

Very ugly but I am not sure how to simplify this, any comments are very appreciated.

I am not sure in these 5 by 5 squares. Are they filters actually? 
If not could anyone please tell how to correctly grab filters from the model?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried to display the weights like so only the first 25. I have the same question that you do is this the filter or something else. It doesn't seem to be the same filters that are derived from deep belief networks or stacked RBM's.

Here is the untrained visualized weights:[image: untrained weights]

and here are the trained weights:

[image: trained weights]

Strangely there is no change after training! If you compare them they are identical.

and then the DBN RBM filters layer 1 on top and layer 2 on bottom:
[image: DBM RBM filters]

If i set kernel_intialization="ones" then I get filters that look good but the net loss never decreases though with many trial and error changes:
[image]

Here is the code to display the 2D Conv Weights / Filters.

```
  ann = Sequential()
  x = Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(5,5),input_shape=(32,32,3))
  ann.add(x)
  ann.add(Activation("relu"))
```

...

```
  x1w = x.get_weights()[0][:,:,0,:]
  for i in range(1,26):
      plt.subplot(5,5,i)
      plt.imshow(x1w[:,:,i],interpolation="nearest",cmap="gray")
  plt.show()

  ann.fit(Xtrain, ytrain_indicator, epochs=5, batch_size=32)

  x1w = x.get_weights()[0][:,:,0,:]
  for i in range(1,26):
      plt.subplot(5,5,i)
      plt.imshow(x1w[:,:,i],interpolation="nearest",cmap="gray")
  plt.show()
```

---------------------------UPDATE------------------------

So I tried it again with a learning rate of 0.01 instead of 1e-6 and used the images normalized between 0 and 1 instead of 0 and 255 by dividing the images by 255.0. Now the convolution filters are changing and the output of the first convolutional filter looks like so:
[image: Untrained Weights]

The trained filter you'll notice is changed (not by much) with a reasonable learning rate:[image: Trained Convolution Filter]

Here is image seven of the CIFAR-10 test set:[image: Image 7 CIFAR-10 Car]

And here is the output of the first convolution layer:
[image: Convolution Layer Output]

And if I take the last convolution layer (no dense layers in between) and feed it to a classifier untrained it is similar to classifying raw images in terms of accuracy but if I train the convolution layers the last convolution layer output increases the accuracy of the classifier (random forest).

So I would conclude the convolution layers are indeed filters as well as weights.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is a really weird thing here: weights are similar in case of random initialization. I am using glorot initialization that is recommended for conv layers. The most confusion question for me is: we are training network but experiencing same weights. What did we train? Have no answer for this...

Comment: So what is the third dimension of the weights?  In `x1w = x.get_weights()[0][:,:,0,:]`, the 0 in `[:,:,0,:]`.  I think the first two dims are the kernel x and y, and the last is the number of kernels-but I have no idea what the 3rd dimension is.  It seems to be the dimension of the previous layer's output, but I don't understand why or what that really means.

Comment: The 0 is the red channel. The three dimensions are red green and blue. The first is x the second is y the third is channel and the last is the nth convolutions layer.

Answer (score 2):

In layer.get_weights()[0][:,:,:,:], the dimensions in [:,:,:,:] are x position of the weight, y position of the weight, the n th input to the corresponding conv layer (coming from the previous layer, note that if you try to obtain the weights of first conv layer then this number is 1 because only one input is driven to the first conv layer) and k th filter or kernel in the corresponding layer, respectively. So, the array shape returned by layer.get_weights()[0] can be interpreted as only one input is driven to the layer and 96 filters with 5x5 size are generated. If you want to reach one of the filters, you can type, lets say the 6th filter
print(layer.get_weights()[0][:,:,:,6].squeeze()).
However, if you need the filters of the 2nd conv layer (see model image link attached below), then notice for each of 32 input images or matrices you will have 64 filters. If you want to get the weights of any of them for example weights of the 4th filter generated for the 8th input image, then you should type
print(layer.get_weights()[0][:,:,8,4].squeeze()).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPaAG.png)